# how can I wrap a control with a div from the code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to add a div tag that can wrap a control from the behind? I want to send a list of controls to my function and have it dynamically add a div around each one, so that each control is within its own div.

Example:
html:

```
...
<p> some text</p>
Name: <asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server" />
...
```

function should work to make the markup look like this-

```
...
<p> some text</p>
Name: <div id="divName" runat="server"><asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server" /></div>
...
```

Comment: Do you really need the `runat="server"` on the div?

Comment: Yes I need the control to run at server so it can be manipulated and accessed by other methods by server side code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and there is more than one way to do this.

**Recommended solution: create a custom control**

You can easily create a custom control that extends `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` and overrides the `Render` method to write the markup for you. This gives you ultimate flexibility in how a control is rendered. This example uses `base.Render()` to render the `TextBox` itself, but wraps it in a `DIV` by writing directly to the `HtmlTextWriter`. The major benefits to this are that your custom control will be available in the code behind just like any other server control and that you can declare it in your .aspx/.ascx files.

To wit:

```
public class WrappedTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<div id=\"div{0}\" runat=\"server\">", this.ID.Replace("txt", String.Empty));
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.WriteEndTag("div");
    }
}
```

To use the control in an ASPX page, first `Register` the control's namespace:

`<%@ Register Assembly="WebApplication1" TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="WebApplication1" %>`

Then add the control to your form like so:

`<cc:WrappedTextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="Wrapped!" />`

`cc` is just an arbitrary prefix that I chose, but you can make up your own! (`cc` for "custom control")

Note that the `runat=\"server\"` is probably unnecessary in the `div` output (though you could be writing code that generates ASPX content, I suppose). The `runat="server"` just tells ASP.NET that you want it to be a server control, but in this case your `WrappedTextBox` is the server control. Also note that this isn't necessarily a best-practices example.. I wouldn't replace the `txt` normally, but rather would use a custom attribute for the div ID. (But this example will give the requested output.)

**Alternate solution: Depth first search and modification of the Control Tree**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeepControlSearch(Page);
    }
    private void DeepControlSearch(Control control)
    {
        if (control.HasControls())
        {
            for (int c = control.Controls.Count - 1; c > -1; c--)
            {
                DeepControlSearch(control.Controls[c]);
            }
        }
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            WrapTextBox((TextBox)control);
        }
    }
    private void WrapTextBox(TextBox textBox)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID = String.Format("div{0}", textBox.ID.Replace("txt", String.Empty));
        div.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        Control parent = textBox.Parent;
        parent.Controls.Remove(textBox);
        div.Controls.Add(textBox);
        parent.Controls.Add(div);
    }
```

The benefit to this approach is that you don't have to create custom controls (which requires a bit of up-front work, but usually is a worthwhile investment because you can reuse them in any ASP.NET project). The `HtmlGenericControl` can be manipulated like any other server control, but it is dynamic and so needs to be in `ViewState` if you want to access it on `PostBack` (unless you want to do it the oldskool way and loop through the posted `Form` elements to get values from dynamic controls).

Not sure I would recommend the second approach; this is really what custom controls are made for.

**Alternate solution #2: emit JavaScript (jQuery makes it really easy) to wrap the controls**

You could use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` to emit some JavaScript or jQuery to do this, for example:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "wrap textboxes",
    "$(document).ready(function(){$('input:text').each(function(){$(this).wrap('<div id=\"div' + this.id.replace('txt', '') + '\"></div>');});});",
    true);
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this for any control type, not just textboxes? I simply used the textbox as an example, application wise I need this to handle any control I am adding. Would it be possible to loop through the controls at the form prerender to do something similar instead?

Comment: Yep; see the latter example for the code that actually wraps the DIV. You can create as many custom controls as you want which is not a bad idea for long term products because you get very fine control over how stuff is rendered, but if you want to traverse the control tree and wrap controls just check for whatever types you want to manipulate. Note how the loop works backwards and the recursive step occurs before the control tree is modified! This is important so that you don't double wrap stuff or get a stack oveflow exception.